# I am trying to fix lint issues in my project, I got stuck with the below error saying missing Required, Pattern parameters does not exists

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

i tried running lint to fix the errors. Can some one help me how can i fix those errors.

Comment: This is a TS compiler error, not a linter error.

Comment: I guess you either explicitly set the type of `errors` or use `let errors =  name.errors || {};` and assuming `name.errors` has the typings correctly, this should work.

Comment: What happens when you use optional chaining? Try to replace all instances to `errors?.required` and `errors?.pattern`.

Comment: @VLAZ where should i type that line in my block of my code?

Comment: @Nik-dev instead of `let errors = {};`

Comment: @VLAZ i tried the same to pattern but it didn't fix. it worked only for required.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that your `errors` is of type `{}` (empty object).

`let errors = {};` should be `let errors: {required?: boolean, pattern?: string} = {}`.

You could also use an interface to do this, like so.

```js
interface IErrors {
  required?: boolean;
  pattern?: string;
}
```

and then `let errors: IErrors = {};`

After writing this answer I saw that you're assigning `errors = name.errors`, so it'd be a better idea to get the type of `name.errors` and use that, rather than making a new interface.

Comment: I would assume that `name.errors` already has the correct type, so making the declaration of `errors` like `let errors = name.errors || {}` should pick it up. Again, assuming the type there is correct.

Comment: I tried this to fix the pattern issue like  let errors = description.errors || {};  is it right way?

Comment: `let errors = description.errors || {};` should be fine, but the compiler may complain that `Property 'required' does not exist on type '{}'.`, since the type of `errors` would be `ErrorType | {}`